# How do I share files between two computers?

Tags: file-sharing

Pulling my hair out trying to find out how to share files between a Ubuntu 12.04 laptop and a Lubuntu 11.10 desktop. Forum searches do not yield specific enough suggestions or do not seem to apply to my version (Where is menu > places, in 12.04?).

I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to share files in Linux, including FTP, SSH, Samba, NFS

If you want to share files and keep them in sync in both machines, probably Samba and NFS are the best options. If you only want to transfer a file from one machine to other probable FTP or SSH would be the simplest.

See the following docs for setting them up:

Samba https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/configuring-samba.html

NFS https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

FTP (on the server side):

sudo apt-get install inetutils-ftpd

SSH (on the server side):

sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using ssh which is fine. I also tried personal file sharing and although I can see the other computer's public folder on my network I can't connect to it. Can't mount device message appears. Sftp now appears in the network column. I don't know which application caused it to appear. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Click on a empty space in your desktop, then take the cursor on top. Click on File > Connect to server >.

Hope it helps